# View all the employees that earn more than a specific person

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I got a table named `EMP` with this structure.

> | EMPNO | ENAME | JOB | SAL | DEPTNO |

I would like to show a list of all employees earning more than 'Jones'. Using SQL query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE sal > (SELECT sal FROM emp WHERE ename = 'Jones');
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually just worked it out myself as well. Thanks for taking the time to answer.